# how to compare selected dropdownlist value with a model property in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC app I have a dropdownlist tied to a model like below

```
class MyObjectViewModel
{
    //comes from WebService, but that doesnt matter here
    List<PersonViewModel> AllPeople= {person1,person2, etc} 
   // PersonViewModel has properties like Id, Name, NeedToInform

    int SelectedPersonId;
}

@model MyModels.MyObjectViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.SelectedPersonId, 
      Model.AllPeople.Select(p=>new SelectListItem{Value = p.Id, Text=p.Name}), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "process(this.value)" })
```

The client side code like like below

```
<script>
 process (val) {
 console.log(val);        
}         
</script>
```

I can get the selected value i.e. Id from PersonViewModel but I need to compare if the selected person from PersonViewModel has the property `NeedToInform` to be true. Not sure how can we do it in the javascript function, something on these lines

```
   <script>
    process (val) {
    console.log(val);
    //Here I need to compare the model like 
    // var doWeneedToInform=@Model.AllPeople.Where(x=>x.Id===val).NeedToInform        
  }         
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>

var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
console.log(JSON.stringify(model));

    process (val) {
    console.log(val);

    let needToInform= null;

model.allPeople.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.Id === val) {
      needToInform = item.NeedToInfom;
     break;
    }
});
        
  }         
</script>
```

if the model is very large , you can use ajax to send a request to a special api that returns data you need.